# Tetriminos Class in UE4

Tags: unreal-engine4, tetris

I'm trying to make a Tetris game on UE4 using mostly C++ My first idea would be a Tetriminos class for the single Tetris pieces

Each Tetriminos has a color and a shape

Now for the hard part: technically a Tetriminos is made of 4 cubes (so I would make a static mesh Cube) to which I have to "attach" the color and, most importantly, the position in the space This is where I start panicking

I have no clue on how implementing this, how, in other words, I should "link" these 4 cube meshes to the class and then positioning them according to the shape (in order to create a T, Z, O, I and L shape made of 4 cubes)

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to use cubes? Wouldn't meshes in the actual letters shapes be better? Unless I'm missing something, an O with four cubes is a diamond, and a Z is made with five cubes.

Regardless, first you need to define connection points for the cubes: at each face and at each edge. You can identify them however you want. Then you need a way to define how a letter is made - which is a list of the combinations of faces and edges.

Does that get you started?